# Response content of HttpResponseMessage on making a Post request is always '{}' in uwp

Tags: c#, uwp, httpresponsemessage

I am making HTTP Post call to a webservice url. In the response I get 200 Status Ok message. But when I try to get the response content using await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync() its always '{}'. The web service returns either SUCCESS or FAILED based on the user credentials passed. How do I retrieve the message. Please help.

Code to make a web service call

```
    public Task<HttpResponseMessage> PostAsJsonAsync<T>(Uri uri, T item)
            {
                var client = new HttpClient();
                var itemAsJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(item);
                var content = new StringContent(itemAsJson);
                //var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(itemAsJson);
                content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json");
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
                return client.PostAsync(uri, content);

            }

     private async void mainPage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
            {
 UserDetails details = new UserDetails()
                {
                    username = composite["username"].ToString(),
                    userpass = composite["password"].ToString()
                };    
    var response = await PostAsJsonAsync(new Uri("http://ec2-xxxx-.compute-1.amazonaws.com:8080/Sanjeevani/rest/SV/login"), details);
                    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode) //I get a 200 code i.e OK
                    {
                        string str = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                        if (str == "SUCCESS") //str is always '{}'
                        {
                            this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(Dashboard), details);
                        }
           }
```

Comment: It looks like the problem originates with the web service. Inspect the request using some thing like fiddler and see what response is actually being returned.

Comment: Sure let me try Fiddler

Comment: can you debug the service? i think the webservice is returning the "{}" so fiddler will only confirm that you are not getting enough data. Maybe it works when settings the accept header too

Comment: Thanks for your response. I just debugged the service. The issue was with the actual web service itself.